# Migrating from CraftCMS to Wordpress (Metadata question)

Tags: migration, seo, meta

My company is working to migrate 7 websites into a single integrated website. However as we are migrating this with our CMS partner we are seeing that no metatitles and metadata are being transferred over. These are all SEO optimized so it would likely result in a KW rank loss if we didn't transfer these over. Any way we can get a bulk export or utilize a plugin to make sure all the metatitles and metadata are transferring over.

Comment: What is currently powering the "metatitles" and "metadata" on the old Craft site? That's not something that occurs naturally, someone would have to architect it.

Comment: If the existing websites have meta titles and descriptions set they would either be set through a plugin (look in the Plugins section of the settings menu) or the developer would have made custom fields for them (which you would need to migrate).

Craft does not have out-of-box meta value fields.